# Only Display last data while grouping in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

How can i display all the data of certain column while grouping in crystal report?
It only display the last record of that column field. Is there any way of displaying  all the records?

Comment: If your field is in the Group Footer, of course it will only display the last record in the group.  Why not put the column in the detail section instead?

Comment: That is not my requirement. Report layout has been design in such a way that i need to kept it in group footer. Is there anyway of appending that column data into one shared value and on condition it will display only the last data?? Otherwise i have to re-think on the storeprocedure so that output matches the layout of the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a formula in the group header: `shared stringVar blah := ''`

Place a formula in the details section: `shared stringVar blah; blah := blah + ',' + {table.field}`

Place a formula in the group footer: `shared stringVar blah`

Sometimes you need to add a line above each of the formulas `whileprintingrecords;`